# Cambiar un texto utilizando CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, wordpress

Necesito cambiar un texto dentro de una etiqueta utilizando CSS. Yo ya intente hacer esto:

```
.course-media .quick-view .btn:before {
display:true;
content: ' Registrate ahora '; 
}
```

Pero este nada más le agrega un texto antes. Tambien intente con `after` pero le agrega un texto después, yo lo que deseo es sustituirlo por completo. 
De antemano gracias

Comment: mira esto te puede servir, aqui explica como lo puedes hacer
http://www.heroesdelaweb.com/threads/cambiar-texto-con-click-solo-css.1547/

Comment: En las respuestas tienes excelentes soluciones, solo quiero comentar que `true` no es un valor de la propiedad `display`.

Answer (score 6):

Realmente si quisieras cambiar el texto **directamente en el DOM** lo tendrías que hacer mediante `Javascript`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
boton.innerHTML = "Adios";
```

```html
<button id="boton">Hola</button>
```

En caso de que lo quisieras hacer si o sí mediante CSS tendrías que hacer alguna especie de "hack" para poder simularlo, **lo que no cambiaría el texto en el DOM de tu página**. Por ejemplo, yo en este caso, ya que estás utilizando el elemento `:before` he dejado un botón vacío que relleno con el contenido ocultando el botón que había anteriormente.

Ejemplo:

```css
div .btn{
   display: none;
}

div > button:before{
  display: block;
  content: "Cualquier cosa";
}
```

```html
<div><button class="btn">Hola</button><button></button></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

En CSS Tricks (ver enlace al final) se muestran y explican cinco formas de sustituir texto. Las explicaciones son bastante orientativas sobre los casos en que convendría usar una u otra forma.

#### 1. Vía jQuery (Menos Marcado / Más JavaScript)

Debe guardar el texto "swap" en alguna parte. Yo diría que en la mayoría de los casos es una preocupación de diseño / visualización por lo que el almacenamiento en el marcado es una buena idea. Usaremos el ejemplo de un botón que intercambia texto entre "Ocultar" y "Mostrar". Un atributo `data-*` es un lugar perfectamente bueno para almacenar el texto de intercambio. Así que se convierte en:

```
<button data-text-swap="Show">Hide</button>
```

Es fácil intercambiar el texto en jQuery:

```
var button = $("button");
button.text(button.data("text-swap"));
```

Pero, si lo haceos así, perderíamos el texto original para siempre. Primero debemos guardar el texto original. Otro atributo `data-*` lo hará:

```
var button = $("button");
button.data("text-original", button.text());
button.text(button.data("text-swap"));
```

Para hacer eso en un evento de clic, usted haría:

```
var button = $("button");
button.on("click", function() {
  button.data("text-original", button.text());
  button.text(button.data("text-swap"));
});
```

Pero eso sólo va en una dirección. Para completar el "intercambio", tendremos que comparar el valor de texto actual del botón para ver si coincide con el texto de intercambio o no. Si lo hace, cambie de nuevo al original. Si no, al texto de intercambio:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var el = $(this);
  if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
    el.text(el.data("text-original"));
  } else {
    el.data("text-original", el.text());
    el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
  }
});
```

#### 2. Vía jQuery (Más Marcado / Menos JavaScript)

Si estamos dispuestos a establecer ese valor de datos-texto-original en el marcado original, podemos simplificar el JavaScript un poco. Podemos utilizar un solo operador ternario para comprobar si el intercambio coincide con el original y realizar la acción correcta basada en la veracidad.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var el = $(this);
  el.text() == el.data("text-swap") 
    ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) 
    : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
});
```

#### 3. Vía Vanilla JavaScript

Soy culpable de usar demasiado jQuery por aquí para cosas que se pueden hacer sin ella. Esto es lo que la primera versión de "menos marcado" se vería en "raw" JavaScript:

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll("button")[0];
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (button.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == button.innerHTML) {
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
  } else {
    button.setAttribute("data-text-original", button.innerHTML);
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
  }
}, false);
```

#### 4. Vía CSS (con jQuery cambiando nombres de clase)

Puesto que esto es una preocupación de la visión y podría ser considerado un "estado", una idea popular es usar JavaScript sólo para cambiar las clases que representan estados y dejar que CSS defina lo que realmente es el cambio visual.

Podríamos usar la clase "on" para representar el estado de intercambio. Entonces esa clase aplicaría un pseudo elemento que cubría la palabra antigua y la reemplazaría con la palabra swap. No creo que los elementos de botón reales con estilo de navegador predeterminado tomar bien a pseudo elemento así que vamos a utilizar un ancla aquí.

```
a {
  position: relative;
}
a.on:after {
  content: "Hide";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

Esto es un poco funky, para ser justos. Creo que esto es casi peor que poner la palabra de intercambio en el JavaScript. CSS no es realmente para este tipo de cosas y probablemente tiene algunas preocupaciones de accesibilidad.

Esto también ocurre porque la palabra "Ocultar" es más pequeña que "Mostrar" un poco. Si la palabra swap era más grande, el original saldría por debajo de la cubierta blanca. Podría ser capaz de evitar que el bloqueo en línea de la original, ocultando el desbordamiento, y patear el original de la caja con el texto de sangría. Pero el hecho de que la palabra de reemplazo está en posición absoluta lo elimina del flujo, lo que podría ser un problema, por no mencionar el diseño del mundo real no siempre es tan simple como flat-color-on-flat-color.

#### 5. Vía sólo CSS

Pero bueno, siempre y cuando nos estamos poniendo funky, podríamos usar el Checkbox Hack aquí para hacer el intercambio de texto completamente CSS. El reemplazo sucede exactamente de la misma manera, sólo sucede cuando una casilla de verificación invisible justo antes de la palabra es: marcada o no. Esto significa que la palabra también debe estar en una etiqueta, que puede cambiar el estado de la casilla de verificación a través del atributo for.

HTML:

```
<input id="example-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="example" id="example">Show</label>
```

CSS:

```
#example {
  position: relative;
}
#example-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
#example-checkbox:checked + #example:after {
  content: "Hide";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

---

#### Fragmentos de código con las cinco vías

```js
$("#example-one").on("click", function() {
  var el = $(this);
  el.text() == el.data("text-swap") 
    ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) 
    : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
});

$("#example-two").on("click", function() {
  var el = $(this);
  if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
    el.text(el.data("text-original"));
  } else {
    el.data("text-original", el.text());
    el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
  }
});

var button = document.getElementById("example-three");
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (button.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == button.innerHTML) {
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
  } else {
    button.setAttribute("data-text-original", button.innerHTML);
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
  }
}, false);

$("#example-four").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#example-four {
  position: relative;
}
#example-four.on:after {
  content: "Hide";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#example-five {
  position: relative;
}
#example-five-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
#example-five-checkbox:checked + #example-five:after {
  content: "Hide";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>1. Vía jQuery (más  marcado / menos javascript)</h2>
<button id="example-one" data-text-swap="Show" data-text-original="Hide">Hide</button>

<h2>2. Vía jQuery (menos marcado / más javascript)</h2>
<button id="example-two" data-text-swap="Show">Hide</button>

<h2>3. Vía Vanilla JS</h2>
<button id="example-three" data-text-swap="Show">Hide</button>

<h2>4. Vía CSS con cambio de clase desde jQuery</h2>
<a id="example-four" href="#0">Show</a>

<h2>5. Vía CSS solamente</h2>
<input type="checkbox" id="example-five-checkbox" />
<label id="example-five" for="example-five-checkbox">Show</label>
```

---

Enlaces:

- [CSS Tricks: Swapping Out Text, Five Different Ways](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/bcyEA)
- [Demo original en Codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/bcyEA)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.boton::before{
content: 'Pasa por encima';
font-size: xx-large;

}
.boton:hover{
color: white;
background-color: green;
}

.boton:hover::before{
content: '¡Hecho!';
font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Selectores, pseudo-clases y pseudo-elementos en CSS</title>
</head>
<body>
<button class="boton"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].